# Fill: SelectCommand.Connection error on derived iDBCommand

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlclient

Before you dowonvote this, please have a look first. I know there numerous threads here with this errormessage, but I haven't found one with this particular problem. I've created a custom command class implementing the IDbCommand interface like this:

```
internal class Prozedur : IDbCommand
    {
        private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand() ;
        private SqlConnection connection;
        string commandtext;
        CommandType commandType;

        public Prozedur(string abfrage)
        {
            commandtext = abfrage;

            commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection = (SqlConnection)new Verbindung();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);

        }

        public static explicit operator SqlCommand(Prozedur v)
        {
            return command;
        }
    ...
```

I'am using the object like this:

```
    internal class Tabelle : DataTable
    {
        DataTable tabelle = new DataTable();

        internal Tabelle(string abfrage)
        {
            Prozedur p = new Prozedur(abfrage);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)p);
            adapter.Fill(tabelle);
        }
    }
```

However, on the `adapter.Fill(tabelle)` i get the Error *“Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.”*. But if i look at the object p, the connection is there:

[image]

#### Update

If i change the code like this

```
    internal class Tabelle : DataTable
    {
        DataTable tabelle = new DataTable();

        internal Tabelle(string abfrage)
        {
            Prozedur p = new Prozedur(abfrage);
            SqlCommand c = (SqlCommand)p;
            //added this line
            c.Connection = p.Connection;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)p);

            adapter.Fill(tabelle);
        }
    }
```

I get a compiler error for `p.Connection;` *C# Cannot implicitly convert type to. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*.

The code for the connection is this:

```
        public IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {

                return connection;
            }

            set
            {
                connection = (SqlConnection)value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need such a class like `Prozedur`? (_It's names sounds like similar to procedure btw_) Why don't you just use these connections, commands and adapters as a local variables in a method? I _strongly_ feels like you are doing something _unnecessary_.

Comment: The reason beeing to implement more specific functions to `Prozedur` (which is german for procedure btw), hence the derived class. I wanted to try this approach with an easy example first, before i implement the rest.

Comment: What is your _complete_ error message by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the convert method. When I change the code as below it works. Basically I had to make all variables static and return a new `SqlCommand`Object in the convert method.

```
 internal class Prozedur : IDbCommand
    {
        private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        private static SqlConnection connection;
        static string commandtext;
        CommandType commandType;

        public Prozedur(string abfrage)
        {
            commandtext = abfrage;
            commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection = (SqlConnection)new Verbindung();
        }

        public static explicit operator SqlCommand(Prozedur v)
        {
            return new SqlCommand() { CommandText = commandtext, Connection = connection, CommandType = command.CommandType };
        }
...
```

And it works like this without static variables:

```
    internal class Prozedur : IDbCommand
    {
        private SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        private SqlConnection connection;
        string commandtext;
        CommandType commandType;

        public Prozedur(string abfrage)
        {
            commandtext = abfrage;
            commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection = (SqlConnection)new Verbindung();
        }

        public static explicit operator SqlCommand(Prozedur v)
        {
            return new SqlCommand() { CommandText = v.CommandText, Connection = (SqlConnection)v.Connection, CommandType = v.CommandType };
        }
...
```